# get auto increment in query as a variable to use in another query

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion

I am inserting into two tables. Into the first table goes a new 'item'. There are a lot of fields, but for simplicity I'll only show you what I need. This is my coldfusion page:

```
<cfquery>
    INSERT INTO my_item_table (itemid, a bunch of other stuff)
    VALUES (itemid_sequence.nextval, a bunch of other stuff)
</cfquery>
```

My issue is I want to insert that auto-incremented itemid as a value into another table, a file-attachment table. The same coldfusion page:

```
<cfquery>
    INSERT INTO my_attachments_table (attachno, itemid, filename)
    VALUES (attachment_sequence.nextval, **AUTO-INCREMENT VALUE HERE**, '#url.fileName#')
</cfquery>
```

I know I could query the item table for the values that were just entered into the first table, but even though it's not likely, there is a possibility that the user input isn't unique, meaning a query of the same fields could return more than one row. In which case, I couldn't get the itemid. The itemid created in the query is the only unique identifier.

My question is: is there a way to set the auto=increment to a value inside the query so I can use it outside? If not, how would you suggest getting my itemid? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by retrieving the next sequence value into a variable with a query like this:

```
SELECT itemid_sequence.nextval FROM DUAL
```

(DUAL is a dummy table in Oracle). You could then proceed to use this variable in both INSERT queries.

Another option: create a stored procedure in the database that will fire both queries for you.

Comment: I'm not an Oracle expert - sounds like Danny knows what he's talking about - but when you do an insert in CF inside of one query and then grab the results of autoincrement in the next query you run the risk of concurrency issues (where another request has incremented the field in the mean time). Make sure and use transactions - or alternatively a stored proc as Danny suggests - to avoid this eventuality.

Comment: Alternatively you could grab the increment value *within* the insert query - returning it as a result.

Comment: How would I set it as a variable? From what I understand, you would cfoutput this query, but there is no column name defined to reference. I.e. how would this work? <cfset itemid="what goes here">

Comment: Ok I got it: SELECT itemid_sequence.nextval AS theVariableName FROM DUAL

Comment: Re. Brian's answer below: for Oracle it would be result.ROWID, but this does not return the row's key -- which is what you're looking for. See http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_17.html, search for ROWID.

Answer (score 5):

If you do an insert via  in ColdFusion 8/9/10, it returns the ID of the inserted row (or rows) in the result attribute of the  tag. For example, if you're using SQL Server, result_name.IDENTITYCOL is the reference to the ID of the inserted row. If you're using MySQL, it's result_name.GENERATED_KEY.

Comment: In Oracle it will return the row ID which is not the primary key of the table.

Comment: rats... I always forgetthat - as of cf8. nice brian.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work with CF8 and MSSQL 2000 (doesn't affect the poster, just stating)

Comment: One other option would be to (in SQL Server 2000 and later) use the @@identity value returned immediately after the INSERT statement and return that to CF (i.e.; select @@identity as newID) and refer to that in the result attribute of the original query (i.e.; query result.newID).